# Objective c - Can't get Auto Layout to work for UIWebView inside UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom UITableView Cell and inside the cell there are many subviews and they all use auto layout, they work fine apart from the UIWebView, i set it inside a UIView at H:|-5-[webView] and V:[webView] but the thing is that my cells dynamically resize and instead of the UIWebView sitting in its UIView the UIWebView sits 5 from the left and 0 from the top of the cell:

Here is the custom UITableViewCell:

```
#import "PostTableViewYoutubeCell.h"

        @implementation PostTableViewYoutubeCell

        @synthesize main;
        @synthesize top;
        @synthesize center;
        @synthesize centerLeft;
        @synthesize centerRight;
        @synthesize bottom;
        @synthesize labelMessage;
        @synthesize labelCat;
        @synthesize labelSubCat;
        @synthesize labelCountry;
        @synthesize labelUser;
        @synthesize labelDate;
        @synthesize imageviewThreadImage;
        @synthesize youtube;
        @synthesize webviewYoutube;
        @synthesize labelYoutubeTitle;

        NSString *vID = @"";

        - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
            self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
            if (self) {
            [self.contentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
            self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

            CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
            CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
            CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
            //CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;

            main = [UIView new];
            [self.contentView addSubview:main];
            main.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [main sizeToFit];
            main.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            top = [UIView new];
            [main addSubview:top];
            top.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [top sizeToFit];
            top.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            labelUser = [UILabel new];
            [top addSubview:labelUser];
            labelUser.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [labelUser sizeToFit];
            [labelUser setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
            labelUser.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(114.0/255.0) green:(114.0/255.0) blue:(114.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];

            labelDate = [UILabel new];
            [top addSubview:labelDate];
            labelDate.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [labelDate sizeToFit];
            [labelDate setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
            labelDate.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(114.0/255.0) green:(114.0/255.0) blue:(114.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];

            center = [UIView new];
            [main addSubview:center];
            center.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [center sizeToFit];
            center.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


            imageviewThreadImage = [UIImageView new];
            [center addSubview:imageviewThreadImage];
            imageviewThreadImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            imageviewThreadImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(207.0/255.0) green:(215.0/255.0) blue:(248.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
            [imageviewThreadImage sizeToFit];

            labelMessage = [UILabel new];
            [center addSubview:labelMessage];
            labelMessage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [labelMessage sizeToFit];
            [labelMessage setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
            labelMessage.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = screenWidth - 10 - 36;
            labelMessage.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
            labelMessage.numberOfLines = 0;
            labelMessage.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            //labelMessage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(207.0/255.0) green:(215.0/255.0) blue:(248.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
            //labelMessage.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

            bottom = [UIView new];
            [main addSubview:bottom];
            bottom.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [bottom sizeToFit];

            labelCat = [UILabel new];
            [bottom addSubview:labelCat];
            labelCat.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [labelCat sizeToFit];
            [labelCat setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
            labelCat.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(58.0/255.0) green:(82.0/255.0) blue:(207.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
            labelCat.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
            labelCat.numberOfLines = 0;

            labelSubCat = [UILabel new];
            [bottom addSubview:labelSubCat];
            labelSubCat.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [labelSubCat sizeToFit];
            [labelSubCat setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
            labelSubCat.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(58.0/255.0) green:(82.0/255.0) blue:(207.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];

            labelCountry = [UILabel new];
            [bottom addSubview:labelCountry];
            labelCountry.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [labelCountry sizeToFit];
            [labelCountry setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
            labelCountry.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(58.0/255.0) green:(82.0/255.0) blue:(207.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];


            youtube = [UIView new];
            [main addSubview:youtube];
            youtube.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [youtube sizeToFit];


            webviewYoutube = [UIWebView new];
            [youtube addSubview:webviewYoutube];
            webviewYoutube.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            //[webviewYoutube sizeToFit];

            [webviewYoutube setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback:YES];
            [webviewYoutube setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction:NO];
            youtube.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(58.0/255.0) green:(82.0/255.0) blue:(207.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
            }

            return self;
        }

        - (void)layoutSubviews
        {
            [super layoutSubviews];
            // Make sure the contentView does a layout pass here so that its subviews have their frames set, which we
            // need to use to set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth below.
            [self.contentView setNeedsLayout];
            [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];

            // Set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth of the mutli-line bodyLabel based on the evaluated width of the label's frame,
            // as this will allow the text to wrap correctly, and as a result allow the label to take on the correct height.
            self.labelMessage.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.labelMessage.frame);
        }

        - (void)updateConstraints {
            [super updateConstraints];

            if (self.didSetupConstraints) return;

            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary7 = @{@"main":main};
            NSArray *constraint_H37 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[main]|"
                                              options:0
                                              metrics:nil
                                            views:viewsDictionary7];

            NSArray *constraint_V37 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[main]|"
                                              options:0
                                              metrics:nil
                                            views:viewsDictionary7];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H37];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_V37];

            //NSString *text = labelMessage.text;

            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary3 = @{@"top":top,@"center":center,@"bottom":bottom,@"youtube":youtube};
            NSArray *constraint_H3 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[top]-5-[center(>=50)]-5-[bottom]-5-[youtube(100)]-10-|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:viewsDictionary3];

            NSArray *constraint_H33cvcv4545 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[youtube]|"
                                                  options:0
                                                  metrics:nil
                                                views:viewsDictionary3];

            NSArray *constraint_H33 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[top]|"
                                              options:0
                                              metrics:nil
                                            views:viewsDictionary3];

            NSArray *constraint_H333 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[center]|"
                                               options:0
                                               metrics:nil
                                             views:viewsDictionary3];

            NSArray *constraint_H3335657 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[bottom]|"
                                               options:0
                                               metrics:nil
                                                 views:viewsDictionary3];

            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary4 = @{@"labelUser":labelUser,@"labelDate":labelDate};
            NSArray *constraint_H4 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[labelUser]|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:viewsDictionary4];

            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary45 = @{@"labelDate":labelDate};
            NSArray *constraint_H4555 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[labelDate]|"
                                            options:0
                                            metrics:nil
                                              views:viewsDictionary45];

            NSArray *constraint_H44 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[labelUser]-20-[labelDate]-5-|"
                                              options:0
                                              metrics:nil
                                            views:viewsDictionary4];

            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary48 = @{@"labelMessage":labelMessage,@"imageviewThreadImage":imageviewThreadImage};



            NSArray *constraint_H48 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[labelMessage]-5-|"
                                              options:0
                                              metrics:nil
                                            views:viewsDictionary48];

            NSArray *constraint_H48342 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-8-[imageviewThreadImage(36)]"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:viewsDictionary48];



            NSArray *constraint_H448345fgdfg = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[imageviewThreadImage(36)]"
                                                   options:0
                                                   metrics:nil
                                                 views:viewsDictionary48];

            CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
            CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
            CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
            //CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;


            NSArray *constraint_H448345fgdfgdfdf454 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-46-[labelMessage(%f)]-10-|",screenWidth - 51]
                                                      options:0
                                                      metrics:nil
                                                    views:viewsDictionary48];




            /**NSArray *constraint_H448 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[labelMessage]-5-|"
             options:0
             metrics:nil
             views:viewsDictionary48];**/

            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary488 = @{@"labelCat":labelCat,@"labelCountry":labelCountry,@"labelSubCat":labelSubCat};
            NSArray *constraint_H488 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[labelCat]|"
                                               options:0
                                               metrics:nil
                                             views:viewsDictionary488];
            NSArray *constraint_H48898 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[labelCountry]|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:viewsDictionary488];
            NSArray *constraint_H48898fgf54 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[labelSubCat]|"
                                                  options:0
                                                  metrics:nil
                                                views:viewsDictionary488];

            NSArray *constraint_H4488 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[labelCat]-10-[labelSubCat]-10-[labelCountry]"
                                            options:0
                                            metrics:nil
                                              views:viewsDictionary488];






            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary8 = @{@"webviewYoutube":webviewYoutube};
            NSArray *constraint_H378 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[webviewYoutube(80)]"
                                              options:0
                                              metrics:nil
                                            views:viewsDictionary8];

            NSArray *constraint_V378 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[webviewYoutube(100)]"
                                              options:0
                                              metrics:nil
                                            views:viewsDictionary8];
            [youtube addConstraints:constraint_H378];
            [youtube addConstraints:constraint_V378];



            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H3];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H33];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H333];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H4];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H44];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H48];
            //[self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H448];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H4555];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H3335657];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H488];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H48342];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H4488];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H448345fgdfg];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H48898];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H48898fgf54];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H448345fgdfgdfdf454];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H33cvcv4545];



            self.didSetupConstraints = YES;

        }


        -(void)setYoutube: (NSString*)youtubeID :(NSString*)title {

             dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                NSString* embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                           <html>\
                           <body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'>\
                           <script type='text/javascript'>\
                           </script>\
                           <iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='%d' height='%d' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1' frameborder='0'>\
                           </body>\
                           </html>", 100, 80, youtubeID];
                [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

                [webviewYoutube loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];




            });
        }





        - (void)awakeFromNib {
            // Initialization code
        }

        - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
            [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

            // Configure the view for the selected state
        }

        @end
```

Comment: Y U No use IB? ..seems like you are missing vertical position constraint. Try `V:|-0-[webViewYoutube(80)]`

Comment: @Jakub Vano, what has happened now with that change is that my cell is half missing and at the point that the cell can be seen on top of the uitableview is where the uiwebview starts. IF you dont understand ill explain more

Comment: Another thing: you are adding all the constraints to the `contentView`. You should be adding constraints to the direct superview, e.g. `constraint_H3` to the `main`.

Comment: @JakubVano, i moved the uiwebview constraints to the bottom of all the other constraints and started working

Comment: `constraint_H448345fgdfgdfdf454` - oh, God... I'm blind